# How to build MacOSX executables on Travis CI?

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I have a small python program that depends only on wxPython. I developed this on Linux and I have managed to set up automatic build of a windows executable using wine on Travis CI (seguid_calculator on github).

My solution involves a combination of a recent wine release and Pyinstaller.

I would like to do a similar thing for MacOS. I understand that there is a MacOSX build environment on Travis as well. I have zero experience with the MacOSX os and I do not own a Mac. I have understood that you can install third party packages using something called "homebrew"

Is there an example out there for what I would like to do? An example travis.yml file would be great!

Thanks for any input,
/Björn

*** Edit ***

I have created a sample wxpython app that only opens a window. It is located at https://github.com/BjornFJohansson/macapp.
I uses the .travis.yml below which produces executables that do not work.

```
os:
- osx
language: objective-c
python:
- '2.7'
before_install:
- brew update
- brew outdated xctool || brew upgrade xctool
- brew install python
- brew install wxpython
- pip install pyinstaller
- pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile hw.py
- ls
- ls dist/
- hdiutil create dist/hw.dmg -srcfolder dist/ -ov
install: true
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: VK1oVWQCRomgcFNVua00B3YSsotezzU1p6/fh73/0vwQFzVMolVnAsnfSq6EAwIcJvakU0TI9pqZR+0S3PKnUs+Kn3Ar8OwQ88t2azZNwewBfKua3tM2/7BF4y7O0gOtN1F29Yxyu0zPInIVY17BqGygibQ1kthBTm+tj3YyNW8=
  file: 
    - "dist/hw"
    - "dist/hw.dmg"
  on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
    repo: BjornFJohansson/macapp
```

basically, first I update xtools (I have seen many do this, so I decided to do it as well). Then I brew install python and wxpython. Then I pip install pyinstaller. I use the pyinstaller command which produces an executable (hw) and an "hw.app" folder under ./dist.

I didnt manage to deploy the .app folder, so I make a .dmg using hdiutil.
I then deploy to github releases.

Could someone tell me what might be wrong with this set up?

The travis log can be found here : https://travis-ci.org/BjornFJohansson/macapp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work ist that the wxPython version installed via homebrew is not 32bit. You need to install the dmg from the wxPython homepage. I found a script that does that there: https://github.com/ayufan/travis-osx-vm-templates/blob/master/scripts/packages.sh

I forked your example and managed to get it running (https://github.com/paulmueller/macapp/releases).

.travis.yml now looks like this:

```
language: objective-c
python:
- '2.7'
before_install:
- which python
- brew install python --universal --framework
- brew install wget
- which python
- export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
- defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
- which python
- python --version
# https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/34470
#- arch -i386 brew install wxpython --universal
- mkdir dl
- cd dl
- wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.2.0-cocoa-py2.7.dmg
- ls
- cd ..
- sudo ./packages.sh
- arch -i386 python -c "import wx; print wx.__version__"
- arch -i386 pip install pyinstaller
- arch -i386 pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile hw.py
- ls
- hdiutil create dist/hw.dmg -srcfolder dist/ -ov
- zip -r dist/hw.zip dist/hw.app
- ls dist/
install: true
deploy:
  provider: releases
  skip_cleanup: true
  api_key:
    secure: KjdN4hSHWU3ZDg6lpDNMB2we9jLayM9C8pwyQrV/Xzq8HNH5eNHP8ScI64tvnS0yJegOXnHFwUhUrkMtEs3X29TKrom+8tJ5E52IdBO7xO8fqOfeugC2239vLzc3tNI6RJX/K7CZTsSRu5U++1RJVgcWYjrCln87DuXG+HZRdOI=
  file: 
    - "dist/hw.dmg"
    - "dist/hw.zip"
  on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
    repo: paulmueller/macapp
```

Comment: I had a friend test your executable on a Mac running Yosemite (10.10.3) . Here are screenshots from the zipped app [zip app](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByF9bZqbql11UkxTYjJqanJ0a3dubzVTZk5HY1NnUmhZLTBN/view?usp=sharing) and [dmg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByF9bZqbql11NWwxT1lOZEtGS0tNRW92NUVzRHgySkU2SGZR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I would vote up this answer, but I dont have enough reputation, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/) states that they are not currently accepting new "multi-os" requests so you will not be able to build for OS-X in any case until Travis CI is upgraded.

In general you will need to get accepted for multi-os then add `os: os-x` to your `.travis.yml` file, (possibly on a branch), then look for how to set python, pyinstaller & wxpython up in OS-X - the home pages for all 3 are very helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `os:` part.

I have a similar problem with deploying a wxPython app on Mac OSx using Travis CI. Unfortunately my setup is a bit more complicated, but it might help solving your problem.

I am using conda to build everything.

My travis config:

```
# Mac OS X Python build
language:
- objective-c
python:
- "2.7"
install:
# install python via brew
- brew install python
# make brews python the system default
- brew link --overwrite python
- which python
- python --version
# pip init
- pip install --upgrade pip
# use anaconda
- pip install conda
- conda init
- conda install --yes matplotlib
- conda install --yes scipy numpy=1.8
- conda install --yes 'numpy<1.9.0'
- conda install --yes wxpython
# final pip installs
- pip install cython
- pip install wheel
- pip install sympy
- pip install git+git://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git@779d07b236a943a4bf9d2b1a0ae3e0ebcc914798
# show packages
- pip freeze
# build extensions
- python setup.py develop
script:
# Create wheel pacakge
- python setup.py bdist_wheel
# Create binary
- ./freeze_pyinstaller/macOSx_bundle_script.sh
before_deploy:
  - export RELEASE_PKG_FILEA=$(ls ./dist/*bin.zip)
  - export RELEASE_PKG_FILEB=$(ls ./dist/*app.zip)
  - export RELEASE_PKG_FILEC=$(ls ./dist/*.whl)
  - echo "deploying $RELEASE_PKG_FILEA to GitHub releases"
  - echo "deploying $RELEASE_PKG_FILEB to GitHub releases"
  - echo "deploying $RELEASE_PKG_FILEC to GitHub releases"
# This section was created with
# sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
# sudo gem install travis
# travis setup releases
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: gQu6BKSo5sucrieOvyLz/kn5Ai+vrnXK6Kdm+WMqzXE6keE0LzujXOHWQX2G2EBl1NCjzvt3HrEvJqwGEjLbduJBBPBHaOy71AfKuHaxRQPlFWMLn2iAVVval3q7xU4kEfjAdS50WmARqh6sT7gMj+pHpg1e3pz1SxybOeC40+k=
  skip_cleanup: true
  # Allow
  file_glob: true
  file: 
    - "${RELEASE_PKG_FILEA}"
    - "${RELEASE_PKG_FILEB}"
    - "${RELEASE_PKG_FILEC}"
  on:
    tags: true
    repo: paulmueller/PyCorrFit
```

I had problems creating an app (probably due to my ancient build system). Therefore I had to replace the binary inside the app folder with a script containing:

```
cd $(dirname "$0")
open -a Terminal.app ./MYAPP.bin
```

Where `MYAPP` is the name of the app and I had previously renamed the binary in the app folder to `MYAPP.bin`.

When the app is launched, Terminal opens and launches the binary.

Here is the release built using Travis:

https://github.com/paulmueller/PyCorrFit/releases/tag/0.8.7travis2

This is a working release built on an old MacBook:

https://github.com/paulmueller/PyCorrFit/releases/tag/0.8.7

In the version built with Travis there was some kind of wxpython error. I don't have a Mac with the latest OSx lying around. Having a look at it might help you (and me maybe).

Comment: I was also contemplating using anaconda and conda all the way, maybe Ill get around to it in the future.